# tar exclude files *.zip

Tags: shell, quoting, wildcards, tar

Why don't `*.zip` patterns work in `tar` :

```
tar cfjv backup.tar.bz2 --exclude mydir/files/*.zip mydir
```

Is there another syntax?

Comment: What is the output of that command? Don't you have to have the `f` flag last before the archive name, i.e. `cjvf backup.tar.z2`? Otherwise it would probably create an archive called `jv`.

Comment: Try quoting the exclusion pattern, i.e. use `--exclude "mydir/files/*.zip"`.

Comment: @Kusalananda : no, `cfjv` works perfectly

Comment: @Kusalananda  It works with quotes: `--exclude "mydir/files/*.zip"` , thanks!

Comment: Good! Yes, I saw later in the manual for `tar` that those very old-style command line switches are handled differently.

Comment: Done, with additional explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to quote the exclusion pattern, `mydir/files/*.zip`, otherwise the shell will expand it (globbing), possibly/probably matching a number of files, and the meaning of you command line will be very different from what you intended.

This means changing you original `tar` command line into

```
$ tar cfjv backup.tar.bz2 --exclude "mydir/files/*.zip" mydir
```

I initially thought there was something up with the `cfjv` switches. These are ancient command line switches and `tar` handles them very differently from more "modern" command line switches (prefixed by `-`). That's why you do **not** get an archive called `jv` even though that's what's following the `f` switch.

The manual for `tar` on Mac OS X mentions this under the "COMPATIBILITY" section:

> The bundled-arguments format is supported for compatibility with historic implementations.  It consists of an initial word (with no leading - character) in which each character indicates an option.  Arguments follow as separate words.  The order of the arguments must match
>        the order of the corresponding characters in the bundled command word.
>        For example,
>
> ```
>       tar tbf 32 file.tar
> ```
>
> specifies three flags t, b, and f.  The b and f flags both require
>        arguments, so there must be two additional items on the command line.
>        The 32 is the argument to the b flag, and file.tar is the argument to
>        the f flag.

Answer (score 0):

To search for all .zip files in current directory and all sub-directories try: this

```
 find ./foldername -type f -name '*.zip'
```

To Exclude all .zip files in current directory and all sub-directories try this:

```
 find ./foldername -type f -name '*.zip' > exclude.txt
```

To Create tar Archive excluding all .zip files in current directory and all sub-directories try this:

```
tar -zcvf backup_foldername.tar.gz -X exclude.txt ./foldername
```